# Como trabajar ValidationException o las Excepciones Con EF Core 6 en Windows Forms

Tags: c#

amigos trabajando mi proyecto en Windows Forms, con VS2022, EF Core 6, DevExpress mas C#, me encuentro en otro problema o dilema, yo en EF 6, tenia un codigo para manejar las excepciones al momento de guardar un registro, ahora tuve un par de Errores que no los miraba px no tener estas, quiero implementarlo en EF Core 6 pero con Windows Forms, he buscado y no encontre, es posible convertir mi codigo o mejorarlo para presentar estas si se dan al guardar, dejo mi codigo, siempre esperando sus comentarios. Hay algunos lineas que encontre buscando en san google pero no funcionan.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Metodo Guardar no Asincronico
    /// </summary>
    public void mpxGuadar()
    {
        _db.SaveChanges();
        //Variable que retorna la cadena de mensajes del Error
        string aoMensaje = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingreso en esta seccion del Error");
            //Obtener todos los errores
            foreach (var aodbentityvalidationresult in ex.Entries)
            {
                //Recorrer todos los errores
                foreach (var aoerror in aodbentityvalidationresult.)
                //    acErrors.AppendLine(String.Format("Campo: {0} - Error: {1}.", aoerror.PropertyName, aoerror.ErrorMessage));
                //return View("BancoConfiguraciones", model);
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Property: " + aoerror.PropertyName + " Error: " + aoerror.ErrorMessage);
                    aoMensaje += aoerror.ErrorMessage;
                    //XtraMessageBox.Show(aoMensaje.ToString(), "Error - CRUD DXA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error - CRUD DXA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            //catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            //{
            if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.InnerException != null &&
                ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.Contains("Cannot insert duplicate key row in object"))
            {
                //throw new DuplicateKeyException("Ya existe un registro con esta llave única.");
                Console.WriteLine($"Ya existe un registro con esta llave única.");
                //XtraMessageBox.Show($"Ya existe un registro con esta llave única.", "Error - CRUD DXA   ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
                //XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error - CRUD DXA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                //throw;
            }

            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error - DXA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "");
            return;
        }
    }el código aquí
```

Comment: [Esto es una opinión persona]: Cuando trabajaba en java recuerdo que hacia cosas como esas, hace años que trabajo en .net y me basta con hacer un solo `catch (Exception ex)` genérico, con el cual tengo toda la información necesaria. El desglose de excepciones especificas solo lo uso cuando realizaré una acción en particular según la excepción, con el objetivo de mantener el correcto funcionamiento del software, pero para algo trivial como mostrar un mensaje al usuario o guardar log, solo uso `Exception`

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu opinion, en lo personal igual lo usaba de esa forma, sencillo, pero me he vistos en casos que hay exepciones o errores que necesitas depurar mas a fondo para saber el error correcto que esta dando la aplicacion, por eso lo modificque la primera vez y ayer me tire un dia completo buscando el error que tenia en mi aplicacion, al final lo encontre depurando paso a paso, tenia un campo calculado y no le agregue el valor por default, asi que perdi el dia de ayer.